# invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo el siguiente programa. El programa es bastante basico, crea un archivo con datos dentro, pide un numero de infectados en general, luego pide el numero de infectados de cada uno, despues compara los infectados de cada uno con los infectados en general y hace calculos. El resultado de estos calculos quiero que los reescriba dentro del archivo del principio

```
def menu():
    op = 0
    while op == 0:
        print("1)Cargar infectados de hoy.")
        print("2)Cargar infectados de cada uno y hacer calculo.")
        print("3)Mostrar puntos.")
        print("")
        op = int(input("Eliga opcion:"))
        return op


def datos():
    inf_t = int(input("Ingrese infectados totales de hoy:"))
    return inf_t


def carga(inf_t):
    print("Carga los numeros de cada uno:")
    rizzo = int(input("Rizzo:"))
    tete = int(input("Tete:"))
    gaston = int(input("Gaston:"))
    colo = int(input("Colo:"))
    simon = int(input("Simon:"))
    ciro = int(input("Ciro:"))

    if rizzo > inf_t:
        rizzo2 = rizzo - inf_t
    elif rizzo == inf_t:
        rizzo2 = -100
    else:
        rizzo2 = inf_t - rizzo

    if tete > inf_t:
        tete2 = tete - inf_t
    elif tete == inf_t:
        tete2 = -100
    else:
        tete2 = inf_t - tete

    if gaston > inf_t:
        gaston2 = gaston - inf_t
    elif gaston == inf_t:
        gaston2 = -100
    else:
        gaston2 = inf_t - gaston

    if colo > inf_t:
        colo2 = colo - inf_t
    elif colo == inf_t:
        colo2 = -100
    else:
        colo2 = inf_t - colo

    if simon > inf_t:
        simon2 = simon - inf_t
    elif simon == inf_t:
        simon2 = -100
    else:
        simon2 = inf_t - simon

    if ciro > inf_t:
        ciro2 = ciro - inf_t
    elif ciro == inf_t:
        ciro2 = -100
    else:
        ciro2 = inf_t - ciro

    return rizzo2, tete2, gaston2, colo2, simon2, ciro2

def calculo(rizzo2, tete2, gaston2, colo2, simon2, ciro2):
    j = 0
    x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    arch = open('puntos.txt', 'r')
    res_carga = [rizzo2, tete2, gaston2, colo2, simon2, ciro2]
    for linea in arch.readlines():
        x[j] = int(linea) + res_carga[j]
        j += 1

    r = x[0]
    t = x[1]
    g = x[2]
    co = x[3]
    s = x[4]
    ci = x[5]

    return (r, t, g, co, s, ci)

    arch.close()

def escribir_archivo(r, t, g, co, s, ci):
    arch = open('puntos.txt', 'w')
    arch.write("Rizzo: " + str(r) + "\n"
               + "Tete: " + str(t) + "\n"
               + "Gaston: " + str(g) + "\n"
               + "Colo: " + str(co) + "\n"
               + "Simon: " + str(s) + "\n"
               + "Ciro: " + str(ci) + "\n")

    arch.close()
def leer_archivo():
    arch = open('puntos.txt', 'r')
    for linea in arch.readlines():
        print(linea)
    arch.close()

def test():
    band = False
    op = -1
    while op != 0:
        opcion = menu()
        if opcion == 1:
            int_f = datos()
            band = True
        elif opcion == 2 and band:
            r, t, g, co, s, ci = carga(int_f)
            r2, t2, g2, co2, s2, ci2 = calculo(r, t, g, co, s, ci)
            escribir_archivo(r2, t2, g2, co2, s2, ci2)
        elif opcion == 3 and band:
            leer_archivo()
        elif opcion > 3:
            print('Ingrese una opcion del menu.')
        elif band == False:
            print('Debe realizar la opcion 1 primero.')


arch = open('puntos.txt', 'a+')
arch.write('1011')
arch.write('\n1039')
arch.write('\n1189')
arch.write('\n1085')
arch.write('\n981')
arch.write('\n974')
arch.close()

test()
```

Pero me salta el siguiente error

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Rizzo: 0\n'

Comment: Creo que el problema esta en la funcion "calculo", como para que se ubiquen rapidamente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu archivo tiene la siguiente estructura:

> ```
> Rizzo: 1093
> Tete: 1120
> Gaston: 1268
> Colo: 1166
> Simon: 1064
> Ciro: 1052
> ```

por lo que tu función cálculo está mal, intentas convertir a entero la linea completa (`int("Rizzo: 1093\n")`, obviamente no representa un entero, de ahí el error.

Puedes usar `str.split` o `str.rsplit` para partir la cadena y quedarte solo con el entero:

```
def calculo(rizzo2, tete2, gaston2, colo2, simon2, ciro2):
    x = [0] * 6
    res_carga = [rizzo2, tete2, gaston2, colo2, simon2, ciro2]
    with open('puntos.txt', 'r') as arch:
        for j in range(6):
            x[j] = int(arch.readline().rsplit()[-1]) + res_carga[j]
    return x
```

Answer (score 0):

Una vez que lo cargas dentro de una lista como haces aquí `res_carga = [rizzo2, tete2, gaston2, colo2, simon2, ciro2]`ya está vuelto un string. Entonces, quieres trabajar con un string, y eso no puede ser posible, así como quieres no, debes transformarlo a enteros.

Comment: Hola! gracias por contestar. Ahora cambie esa linea de esta forma:  x[j] = int(linea) + int(res_carga[j]). Ya el error no salta mas, pero ahora el problema es que no me devuelve los resultados que quiero. Me devuelve nada mas los de la lista x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] pero en la linea x[j] = int(linea) + res_carga[j] intento cambiar los valores de dicha lista a los de la suma